# How to use Java generics to avoid overwriting inherited methods (template-like behaviour)?

Tags: java, templates, generics, inheritance

I want to make a Graph consiting of Nodes in Java. The graph class will be used by different people and different algorithms, so we will need different Node classes for each case, let's say `DefaultNode` and `SpecialNode extends DefaultNode`.

Now I want `DefaultNode` to contain all the general stuff that a Node needs to work, like for example a list of direct neighbours. So I implement this list in `DefaultNode`:

```
List<DefaultNode> neighbours = new ArrayList<DefaultNode>();
```

My problem is now, that I obviously also need this list in the `SpecialNode` class, but there it should contain and return SpecialNodes. Of course I could overwrite the list and `addNeighbour()` as well as `getNeighbours()` methods in every class that inherits from `DefaultNode`, but that seems redundant and not how OOP is meant to work. I think this would be a perfect case to use templates (like in C++), but afaik there is no such construct in Java, leaving us with Generics.

The solution I came up with so far is the following:

```
interface INode {}

class DefaultNode<T extends INode> implements INode {

    List<T> neighbours;

    List<T> getNeighbours(){}

    void addNeighbour(T node){}

}
```

here, the `<T extends INode>` brackets describe the possible neighbours of this node. So for a `SpecialNode` I would do:

```
class SpecialNode extends DefaultNode<SpecialNode> {}
```

now, while this seems to work as intended, it kind of feels strange... I was surprised that I could not find an easier solution, as this situation seems relatively common. How would you solve this? Is there a better/simpler approach that I missed? Or is the above a viable approach?

Comment: If `getNeighbors` is in `DefaultNode`, what methods are in the interface?  I.e., if you have an `INode` but don't know exactly what type it is, what can you actually do with it?

Comment: You're right, the interface does not make a lot of sense here, as the neighbour list and add/get-methods cannot be in there. Though it might contain additional methods describing a node in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your approach. In fact, some standard interfaces, such as [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) are defined in exactly this way:

```
public class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit> {
             ^^^^^                       ^^^^^
```

Comment: Oh, I should have seen that myself..! Thanks! So the above approach is not wrong... but I'm still interested if there is an easier way... because it seems so simple: 'List<this.getClass()> neighbours;' or something like that...

Comment: @AlexK: `List<this.getClass()>` won't work because of type erasure.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to force that the neighbours of a node are of the same type, you can use:

```
class DefaultNode<T extends DefaultNode<T>> implements INode
```

though I would make the interface generic (and just call it Node not INode).

Comment: but this seems to make it impossible to instantiate DefaultNode: `DefaultNode<DefaultNode> node = new DefaultNode<DefaultNode>();` does not compile. It does force using SpecialNode with SpecialNodes only, so it may be worth introducing an extra abstract class in the inheritance sequence..

Comment: That is another reason to put the generics on the interface then :).

Comment: True. Although that means I have to create a new list and implement the methods in every subclass, which I wanted to avoid in the first place :)
but this is nitpicking I guess, am happy with the abstract-class-solution!

Comment: That does not force the neighbors to be the same type. Consider `class A extends DefaultNode<A>` and `class B extends DefaultNode<A>`

Comment: So how does it differ from my original definition of `DefaultNode`? The only difference I can find is the compilation error when trying to do `DefaultNode<DefaultNode> node = new DefaultNode<>()`